# `seq` takes a very long time with `by=1`

Tags: r

I noticed something strange today, in some cases adding `by=1` to `seq` function introduces a large inefficiency.

```
> system.time(seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> system.time(seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200, by=1))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.42    8.39   18.20
```

At first glance the results are equivalent:

```
> all.equal(seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200),
+           seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200, by=1))
[1] TRUE
 TRUE
```

The difference seems to be that omitting `by=1` causes  the result to be numeric, even if `by` is explicitly integer.

```
> identical(seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200),
+           seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200, by=1))
[1] FALSE
> class(seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200))
[1] "integer"
> class(seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200, by=1L))
[1] "numeric"
```

Also, calling directly to `seq.int` (assuming that is what happens behind the scenes in `seq`) also takes much longer than the `seq` without any arguments:

```
> system.time(seq.int(from=936144000, to=1135987200, by=1L))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    1.68    2.81
```

How do I properly specify `by` to avoid the inefficiency or to get the efficiency of omitting `by`?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0    RUnit_0.4.32      tools_4.1.0       geneorama_1.7.3   data.table_1.14.0
```

Comment: Even faster would be to just do `936144000:1135987200`. Which is about 42 times faster then `seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200)`.

Comment: @Baraliuh great idea and very practical, but it avoids the issue that I was carefully identifying. Also, `seq(from=936144000, to=1135987200)` is already taking 0 seconds, so I think it's using `:` under the covers. I prefer `seq` for more control and ease of reading, and it should work (although again, good point / idea).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to assume what happens behind the scenes, you can run `debug(seq)` and see what the difference is.  It's a generic function, and it calls `seq.default`.

In `seq.default` it turns out that if the `by` argument is missing (and some other conditions which hold in your example), `seq(from, to)` does `from:to`.  This is extremely fast, because it doesn't even allocate the full vector:  in recent versions of R, it is stored in a special format with just the limits of the range.

The other thing you can see if you look at `seq.default` is that the only way to get this output is to have `missing(by)` be `TRUE`.  So the answer to your question is that you can't specify `by` to get the same speed.

@Baraliuh's advice is good:  if you want `seq(from, to, by=1)`, use `from:to` instead.

Comment: good analysis and you appear to be correct, but it's hard to swallow that the best approach is to know the internals well enough to know that you shouldn't be too specific in certain common situations. This feels like a bug to me.

Comment: I recommend bringing this up on the `r-devel@r-project.org` mailing list (but my advice would be *not* to call it a bug *per se*, folks are very sensitive about that).

Comment: @geneorama:  I think it's pretty common in any computing situation to need to know internals (or do lots of testing) to know the most efficient way to do stuff.  It's the same in lots of situations in R, e.g. vectorized calculations are way faster than loops handling one element at a time.  It's not a bug if it gives the right answer but takes longer.

Comment: @BenBolker I have been around long enough to know that R has no bugs. I chose my words carefully "feels like a bug" to lure someone else into calling it a bug. lol

Comment: @geneorama:  R has lots of bugs.  A few are fixed in each new release, and a few new ones are added to replace them.  Just look at the NEWS files.

Comment: "infelicity" is the word R people tend to use (I think it comes from Bill Venables) for things that are unfortunate but aren't bugs ...